# Does every undecidable problem contain a decidable subset?

Tags: formal-languages, undecidability

I know being a decidable language doesn't necessarily mean that every subset is of it is decidable, but does every undecidable language contain a decidable subset?

Comment: Hint: is the empty language decidable? What about languages containing single strings?

Comment: @jmite I feel really stupid now... Of course, the empty language (and any language which contains a single string) is regular and therefore decidable. And a subset of any undecidable language is i.e. the empty set. Thanks, for your help. You can answer the question if you want and I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The empty language is decidable and subset of every other language.
You can also say that every undecidable language has a superset which is decidable ($\Sigma^\ast$ for example).